# Is it possible to pass and use sql inside a sql parameter?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm working with a query that is used by multiple services but the number of results returned are different based on filtering.

To avoid copying and pasting the query, I was wondering if it was possible to pass in piece of sql into a sql parameter and it would work?  I'm also open to alternative solutions.

EXAMPLE:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("filter", "and color = blue");

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(“select * from foo where name = 'Joe' :filter”, parameters, new urobjRowMapper());
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way, because parameters are not part of sql statement and they are not parsed at parse time. They substitute the data, so only dynamic SQL is possible with such approach. But this may cause SQL injection if you do not have a full control over parameter's content

Comment: This is the recipe for disaster. I remember back in 2010 a developer requested a similar thing. He wanted to have a "secret page" in the app where we could type any SQL statement and the app would run it: "it would be way easier to debug issues", he said. He was let go a year later.

Comment: I would like to add that these filters will be constants so I'm not worried about sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

It is very dangerous and fragile to let callers pass SQL to your program, because it opens you up to SQL injection - the very problem the parameters are there to prevent.

A better approach is to pre-code the filters in your query, and protect them by a special "selector" parameter:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE name='Joe' AND
(
    (:qselect = 1 AND color='blue')
OR  (:qselect = 2 AND startYear = 2021)
OR  (:qselect = 3 AND ...)
)
```

Comment: I would like to add that these filters will be constants so I'm not worried about sql injection.

Comment: @Aloha_Scope If the filters are constants, there's no reason to keep them outside the query. List them in the query, and use a selector to pick which one is actually used.

Comment: That's fine.  I should have mentioned that I was open to alternative solutions aside from asking if it should work.